# How do I disable network location windows after unattended installation?

Tags: unattended

after I deployed an unattended windows 7 installation to a client, the network location windows still pops up even though I set the XML settings to "work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this myself. Just set a GPO in Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Network List Manager Policies\All Networks. Change Network Location to "User cannot change location"